# Best way to associate phone numbers with names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, contacts, google-contacts-api, import-contacts

My application stores lots of its users friends' phone numbers. I'd like to allow users to associate names with these phone numbers, but I don't want to make users manually type in names (obviously).

I'm curious what the best overall approach is here, as well as the best way to implement it

Overall approach-wise, I imagine using Gmail / Yahoo / Windows Live contacts is best (the Facebook API doesn't let you access phone numbers), though the gems I've found for interacting with these contacts APIs ([this](http://github.com/cardmagic/contacts) and [this](http://github.com/mislav/contacts)) only give you access to the names and email addresses of each contact.

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't have phone numbers in Gmail's contacts.

You can allow to import phone book via vCard or do smth to impot from iPhone/Android

Alternatively, you can write a custom parser for google's phone book or use gData API (not sure if it supports it)